# Problem to use sieve and dovcot to move spam mail to Junk folder

Tags: postfix

I have a working mailserver with postfix, dovecot and Spamassassin. Spamassassin marks mail as spam, but I cant use sieve to move spammail to Junk folder.

If I run `dovecot -n` I can see

```
protocol lda {
   mail_plugins = " sieve"
}   
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = " sieve"    
}
```

If I try to test sieve with telnet it looks like it works

```
$ telnet localhost 4190
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
```

But spammail lands in Inbox and not Junk

If I run the following sieve-filter from cmd the roules in .dovecot.sieve works and move spammail to Junk

```
$ sieve-filter -v -C -e -W -u jesper .dovecot.sieve 'INBOX'
```

Comment: Not saying that will resolve your issue - but may be a good start - I guess there should be no space in mail_plugins sieve confiuration - "sieve".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like adding

> mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver

to

> /etc/postfix/main.cf

and

> dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
>   flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f > 
>   ${sender} -d ${recipient}

to

> master.cf

solved the problem